# risks of exposing Kestrel to outside world

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-core

i know that it`s not recommended to expose Kestrel web server to outside world, but the performance lost by placing Kestrel behind IIS is not some thing that can easily be ignored. (in fact one might lose all the performance gained by migrating to .net core.)

so i like to give it a try:

im wondering if there is some thing that i should be aware of when exposing Kestrel to outside world, specially in terms of security?

thanks in advance.

Comment: If iis does not fit your perfomance requirements, maybe nginx will?

Comment: @Evk it is not about IIS, it`s about using a reverse proxy.

Answer (score 3):

The security risks are somewhat ill-defined, but the basic answer is that Kestrel does not have the hardening against attacks that more mature web servers (like IIS) do.

A full write-up is available in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/. Here is the relevant section:

> The most important reason for using a reverse proxy for edge
>   deployments (exposed to traffic from the Internet) is security.
>   Kestrel is relatively new and does not yet have a full complement of
>   defenses against attacks. This includes but isn't limited to
>   appropriate timeouts, size limits, and concurrent connection limits.